# reCAPTCHA (Zend_Service_ReCaptcha) throws "Unable to Connect to tcp://api-verify.recaptcha.net:80"

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, captcha, recaptcha

I am using reCAPTCHA on [this page](https://forum.esfcr.cz/registration.htm) but when I submit I get following error in my apache log:
This started happening after I set ssl to true (i have to use it, becouse website is SSL)

[`Wed Jul 28 18:47:54 2010] [error] [client X.X.31.80] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Unable to Connect to tcp://api-verify.recaptcha.net:80. Error #110: Connection was inactive for a long time' in /XXX/local/XXX-php-XXX/library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php:235\nStack trace:\n#0 /XXX/local/XXX-php-XXX/library/Zend/Http/Client.php(976): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->connect('api-verify.reca...', 80, false)\n#1 /usr/local/XXX-php-XXX/library/Zend/Service/ReCaptcha.php(487): Zend_Http_Client->request('POST')\n#2 /usr/XXX/XXX-php-XXX/library/Zend/Service/ReCaptcha.php(502): Zend_Service_ReCaptcha->_post('03AHJ_Vuuj0ZWOY...', 'adaptors of')\n#3 /XXX/XXX/XXX-php-XXX/XXX/registration.php(111): Zend_Service_ReCaptcha->verify('03AHJ_Vuuj0ZWOY...', 'adaptors of')\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /XXX/local/XXX-php-XXX/library/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php on line 235, referer: https://forum.esfcr.cz/registration.htm`

Anyone who knows what is happening? As you see, I am using SSL.
My PHP code is:

```
$recpatcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha(
                '6LdXXXXXXXXXXXXX9uy_D6rKXXXq9eM',
                '6LdXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXndQ5X9ny',
                array('ssl' => true),
                array ('theme' => 'white', 'timeout' => 800));
```

and $POST processing:

```
$resp = $recpatcha->verify($_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found solution.
Problem was in firewall, which blocks outgoing connections.